# Filter List of Maps

Tags: flutter, list, loops, dart

Here a list of maps :

```
List values = [
  {'title': 'a', 'count': 1},
  {'title': 'b', 'count': 2},
  {'title': 'b', 'count': 8},
  {'title': 'c', 'count': 1},
  {'title': 'a', 'count': 4},
  {'title': 'a', 'count': 9},
]
```

I'm trying to create a new List of maps looks like this :

```
List myList = [
  {
    "title": "a",
    "values": [
      {
        {'title': 'a', 'count': 1},
        {'title': 'a', 'count': 4},
        {'title': 'a', 'count': 9},
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "values": [
      {
        {'title': 'b', 'count': 2},
        {'title': 'b', 'count': 8}
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "a",
    "values": [
      {
        {'title': 'c', 'count': 1},
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I found a solution using `for` loop.
But is there any other solution to create list : `myList`?.

Edit :

Here my solution:

```
createList(List values) {
    List list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (list.any((element) => element['title'] == values[i]['title'])) {
        list
            .firstWhere((e) => e['title'] == values[i]['title'])['values']
            .add(values[i]);
      } else {
        list.add({
          'title': values[i]['title'],
          'values': [values[i]]
        });
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: Probably not. Unless you're able to change how the initial list is generated, mapping your list into a different structure is always going to require iterating over the whole list in some capacity. If you can post your working code, that could be helpful.

Comment: I agree with @robere2. Posting your currently-working code would be very useful. If it's ok (O(n) complexity), I don't think you may improve it

Comment: @robere2 Thanx, I added my working code.

Comment: @HamouOuyaba What goal are you trying to accomplish? Is the issue that this code is too slow on large data sets?

Comment: @robere2 Well i was trying to find the  best solution, as you said i have a large data set. this is just a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to preface my answer by saying I am not very experienced with Dart, so please pardon any syntax errors. Perhaps someone can come in and fix them for me.

This is a [code complexity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Unfortunately there is no way to remove loops entirely, as you obviously have to iterate over each value at least once to get the value. Therefore, the best solution will have a Big O notation of O(n).

However, in the code you posted, you're using `firstWhere` and `any` within your `for` loop, which are both going to have a worst-case complexity of O(n). When added together with your for loop, your method has a complexity of O(n^2), which is generally not ideal.

Your algorithm can be optimized by squishing this down into a single for loop with O(n) complexity. Here is how I would likely go about implementing something like this.

```dart
/// values is expected to be of the form:
/// [
///   {'title': 'a', 'count': 1},
///   {'title': 'b', 'count': 2},
///   {'title': 'b', 'count': 8},
///   {'title': 'c', 'count': 1},
///   {'title': 'a', 'count': 4},
///   {'title': 'a', 'count': 9},
/// ]
createList(List values) {

    Map valueMap = {};
    // Start by converting your list into a map where the keys are the title and the value is an array of your original entries
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        // If this "title" entry doesn't exist yet, make a list for it.
        if(valueMap[values[i]["title"]] is! List) {
            valueMap[values[i]["title"]] = [];
        }
        // Add the value to that list
        valueMap[values[i]["title"]].add(values[i]);
    }
  
    // valueMap should now have a structure like:
    // {
    //  "a": [{"title": "a", "count": 1}, {"title": "a", "count": 4}, {"title": "a", "count": 9}],
    //  "b": [{"title": "b", "count": 2}, {"title": "b", "count": 8}],
    //  "c": [{"title": "c", "count": 1}]
    // }

    // Now convert your map back into a List
    List newValueList = [];
    valueMap.forEach((key, value) => {
        newValueList.add({
            "title": key,
            "values": value
        })
    });
  
    // newValueList should now have a structure like:
    // [
    //   {
    //     "title": "a",
    //     "values": [{"title": "a", "count": 1}, {"title": "a", "count": 4}, {"title": "a", "count": 9}]
    //   },
    //   {
    //     "title": "b",
    //     "values": [{"title": "b", "count": 2}, {"title": "b", "count": 8}]
    //   },
    //   {
    //     "title": "c",
    //     "values": [{"title": "c", "count": 1}]
    //   }
    // ]
  
    return newValueList;
  }
```

This code does not include any nested for loops, and as such, it is an O(n) complexity function.

(Technically, there are two for loops, so you may think that the complexity is actually O(2n). Constants are typically stripped from big-o notation as their impact on the performance is negligible and does not change based on the size of the data set).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, which starts with unique titles.

```
final result = values
    .map((v) => v['title'])
    .toSet()
    .map((title) => {
          'title': title,
          'values': values.where((v) => v['title'] == title).toList()
        })
    .toList();
print(result);
```

Another one with groupBy:

```
final result = groupBy(values, (v) => v['title'])
  .entries
  .map((g) => {'title': g.key, 'values': g.value})
  .toList();
print(result);
```

Comment: Note, this is less efficient than simply using a `for` loop. This has worst-case O(n^2) complexity, while a single `for` loop will be O(n). If your goal is to remove the physical `for` loop from your code, this will do, however if your goal is to improve efficiency, this isn't the answer you're looking for.